# Rails : instance variables does not remain when reload page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a HTML page, in that page, there some options for User to select, this will affect how content will display.

I save those options by using instance variable in controller. For example :

```
class ShopController < ApplicationController

def index
   @option1 = option1 # instance variable option1, contains some information on the form
end

end
```

In this page, I have a form for user input information. When user presses submit button, `ShopControler` will process those information. But at that time, when I check @option1 variable --> NIL. It means : this is an another instance of `ShopController`.

Please give me a solution for the problem that I meet, that I can save information, and can reuse although user has summit form.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about storing it in a session variable?

```
session[:option1] = option1
```

Then when you're done with it just do a

```
session.delete(:option1)
```

This will allow you to use it through multiple requests.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when a user submits a form it will be routed to the create or update action. Unless you specifically have it routed to the index action your problem is most likely that you're not setting @option1 in the action the form is being submitted to.

If you find you are setting it in every action consider using a before_filter to set it.